# Targeting Android SDK 14 or greater causes my app to not display

Tags: android

When targeting Android SDK 12 my app displays perfectly fine on my Galaxy Nexus.  The whole view is essentially a WebView.  Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout">
    <com.hudson.component.HWebWebView android:id="@+id/browser"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">    </com.hudson.component.HWebWebView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The HWebWebView just extends the WebView to provide extra functionality.

[image: Here is everything working]

I started the process of moving to target Android SDK 15 and suddenly I get this.

[image: Here is the display messed up]

The problem is I just don't know where to start looking to figure out exactly what is wrong.   Any starting points would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** So digging around the main body of my code and commenting it out I finally found what the error was.  In the manifest I had

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="false" android:largeScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"></supports-screens>
```

I needed

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"></supports-screens>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd try is dropping back to a regular WebView instead of your HWebWebView class to see if that works. If it does, that narrows down the problem.

Another thing you can try is using a delegate pattern instead of extending WebView. What I mean is have your code or XML instantiate a Webview, get a handle to that view, and call methods on it. All the examples I've seen work that way.

Answer (score 0):

So digging around the main body of my code and commenting it out I finally found what the error was.  In the manifest I had

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="false" android:largeScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"></supports-screens>
```

I needed

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"></supports-screens>
```